# NX "Could not find shadowed session" error

Tags: nx-client, nx-server

I just installed FreeNX on my Ubuntu box:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team/ppa
aptitude update
aptitude install freenx
```

Using the NoMachine nxclient, I'm selecting Shadow Session and I can authenticate, then I see two sessions. Whichever one I choose, I get:

```
NX> 203 NXSSH running with pid: 8266
NX> 285 Enabling check on switch command
NX> 285 Enabling skip of SSH config files
NX> 285 Setting the preferred NX options
NX> 200 Connected to address: 18.26.1.105 on port: 1122
NX> 202 Authenticating user: nx
NX> 208 Using auth method: publickey
HELLO NXSERVER - Version 3.2.0-74-SVN OS (GPL, using backend: 3.4.0)
NX> 105 hello NXCLIENT - Version 3.2.0
NX> 134 Accepted protocol: 3.2.0
NX> 105 SET SHELL_MODE SHELL
NX> 105 SET AUTH_MODE PASSWORD
NX> 105 login
NX> 101 User: yang
NX> 102 Password: 
NX> 103 Welcome to: zs user: yang
NX> 105 listsession --type="shadow"
NX> 127 Sessions list of user '.*' for reconnect:

Display Type             Session ID                       Options  Depth Screen         Status      Session Name
------- ---------------- -------------------------------- -------- ----- -------------- ----------- ------------------------------
0       Local            B0A78F00E6F8B62BC425716AA9567A47 --------                      Running     X0 (Local)
0       Local            48F6DA54F1323220A25B04DADFC36C54 --------                      Running     X0 (Local)


NX> 148 Server capacity: not reached for user: .*
NX> 105 listsession --type="shadow"
NX> 127 Sessions list of user '.*' for reconnect:

Display Type             Session ID                       Options  Depth Screen         Status      Session Name
------- ---------------- -------------------------------- -------- ----- -------------- ----------- ------------------------------
0       Local            B0A78F00E6F8B62BC425716AA9567A47 --------                      Running     X0 (Local)
0       Local            48F6DA54F1323220A25B04DADFC36C54 --------                      Running     X0 (Local)


NX> 148 Server capacity: not reached for user: .*
NX> 105 attachsession  --link="lan" --backingstore="1" --encryption="1" --cache="16M" --images="64M" --shmem="1" --shpix="1" --strict="0" --composite="1" --media="0" --session="zs" --type="shadow" --client="linux" --keyboard="pc105/us" --id="48F6DA54F1323220A25B04DADFC36C54" --display="0"

NX> 596 Could not find shadowed session 48F6DA54F1323220A25B04DADFC36C54. Session failed.
NX> 280 Exiting on signal: 15
```

Any hints? Googling has not been fruitful. Thanks in advance for any help.